# How to select data from old database and insert it into new one within doctrine migration?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework3, doctrine-migrations

I use 'doctrine/DoctrineORMModule' module for zend framework 3 (MVC). I have configured 'orm_default' and can configure 'orm_old' but don't know how to use 'orm_old' within migration file.

I can do this within migration file:

```
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES ('some_value','','',NULL,NULL,'1');";

    $this->addSql($sql);
//...
```

But in general I need run something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.T2(id, title, description) 
SELECT id, title, description FROM DB1.T1;
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to use Doctrine Migrations for two database connections: `orm_default` and `orm_old`.

This is possible in Doctrine, but not with the Zend Framework DoctrineORMModule. This is mentioned very shortly in the official documentation: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/migrations.rst#multiple-migration-configurations

The best thing you can do is to use two separate cli-config files with the same database connections, and put the migrations in two seperate folders. You can then use the 'default' doctrine CLI tools (vendor/bin/doctrine migrations:migrate ) to run migrations for the two connections.

Adding this functionality to the DoctrineORMModule was requested, but never implemented. You can read more about it right here:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/537

Comment: What if I will run that queries under root db user? Is this better option?

Comment: Because you are using seperate configs for the two entitymanagers, there will be no need to use a root user. You can just use different users.